# MDX - Find earliest date by using earliest Year-Month

Tags: filter, mdx, cube

I'm trying to get the first retail price and the date they were set on.

Our database is quite large and includes information from multiple countries, so if I try to target DATE directly, the query times out.

I figured if I narrow the year and month first, it might be easier to get the date by using them as filters.

The following code works by telling me the Year-Month

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[First Month] AS
FILTER([Date].[Year Month].[Year Month].MEMBERS, [Measures].[Item Retail Price]).ITEM(0).NAME

SELECT
{[Measures].[First Month], [Measures].[Item Retail Price]} ON 0,
[Item].[Item Code].[Item Code].MEMBERS ON 1

FROM ( SELECT ( { [Item].[Category Code].&[558] } ) ON COLUMNS
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Item].[Company].&[CANADA] } ) ON COLUMNS
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Reporting Currency].[Reporting Currency].[CAD - Canadian dollar] } ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [DATABASE]))) 
    
WHERE ( [Reporting Currency].[Reporting Currency].[CAD - Canadian dollar], [Item].[Company].&[CANADA], [Item].[Category Code].&[558] )
```

My problem is trying to use [First Month] to filter [Date]. The code below returns #ERROR for the [First Date] column.

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[First Month] AS
FILTER([Date].[Year Month].[Year Month].MEMBERS, [Measures].[Item Retail Price]).ITEM(0).NAME

MEMBER [Measures].[First Date] AS
FILTER([Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS, [Date].[Year Month].[Year Month] = [Measures].[First Month] AND [Measures].[Item Retail Price]).ITEM(0).NAME

SELECT
{[Measures].[First Date], [Measures].[Item Retail Price]} ON 0,
[Item].[Item Code].[Item Code].MEMBERS ON 1

FROM ( SELECT ( { [Item].[Category Code].&[558] } ) ON COLUMNS
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Item].[Company].&[CANADA] } ) ON COLUMNS
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Reporting Currency].[Reporting Currency].[CAD - Canadian dollar] } ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [DATABASE])))

WHERE ( [Reporting Currency].[Reporting Currency].[CAD - Canadian dollar], [Item].[Company].&[CANADA], [Item].[Category Code].&[558] )
```

If it's not obvious, I'm still very green when it comes to MDX and so please forgive my possible crude formatting and statements

Answer (score 0):

If you double click the '#Error' cell in SSMS, you would get the actual detailed error.

The actual error is likely to give clues to fix the issue.

Sample below using a made up error using Adventure Works sample:

[image]